# aiogram как записать данные из callback в state?

Tags: python, python-3.x, aiogram, бот, telegram

Всем здравствуйте! Как можно данные из callback передать в state (на выходе должен получиться словарь)

```
@dp.message_handler(state=Message_User.message_product_id, 
content_types=types.ContentTypes.TEXT)
async def state_3(message: types.Message, state: Message_User):
    try:int(message.text)
    except:
        await message.reply("Пожалуйста, повторите ID:")
        return

    await state.update_data(prID=message.text.title())

    markup = types.InlineKeyboardMarkup()
    markup.add(types.InlineKeyboardButton("Ключ", callback_data='product_tip_event_key'))
    markup.add(types.InlineKeyboardButton("Аккаунт", callback_data='product_tip_event_account'))
    markup.add(types.InlineKeyboardButton("Гифт", callback_data='product_tip_event_gift'))

    await message.answer(text='Выберите тип товара', reply_markup=markup)
    #await Message_User.message_product_tip.set()



#ACTIVATION
@dp.callback_query_handler(lambda event: event.data.startswith('product_tip_event_'))
async def call_send_message(event: types.callback_query.CallbackQuery, state: Message_User):
    await state.update_data(prTip=event.data.replace('product_tip_event_',''))
    await message.answer(text='Введите тип активации:')
    await Message_User.message_product_activation.set()
```

Comment: Так вы вроде бы его и так добавляете. В чем конкретно проблема?

Comment: Почему-то в функцию call_send_message не переходит

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Попробуй поменять это

```
@dp.callback_query_handler(lambda event: event.data.startswith('product_tip_event_'))
async def call_send_message(event: types.callback_query.CallbackQuery, state: Message_User):
```

На это

```
@dp.callback_query_handler(text_startswith='product_tip_event_', state=Message_User)
async def call_send_message(event: types.CallbackQuery, state: FSMContext):
```

Comment: Вы мой спаситель. Огромное спасибо! Единственно что, поменяйте state FSMContext из функции, на Message_User. (тот, что используется мной)

Comment: Увы, но вы не правы. ФСм контекст я поставил правильно так как нам нужны подсказки именно от него. Месседж юзер я поместил в декоратор выше, он там как фильтр, который говорит что этот колбек хендлер сработает только если текущий стейт равен вашему месседж юзеру. А то что внутри функции это сам стейт, и наследоваться он должен именно от ФСм контекста.

Comment: Но почему тогда с Message_user в функции всё работает, как и планировалось ?

Comment: Потому что ФСм контекст это просто подсказка для автопополнения иде